# What is CollectionType, Category and Component in Strapi

Tags: content-management-system, strapi

Can someone explain what does `CollectionType`, `Category` and `Component` mean in `Strapi` and the relation between each other and what can belong to what. `Strapi` 's documentation is missing all these details. So someone with Strapi knowledge can explain.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the docs are missing on these points.

Collection Types are to manage list of content. eg. articles, products, ...

Category (I'm not sure what you are talking about) if it's in the Component section, it's just to group your compost in a same folder.

Components are a content structure that could be use in Content Types (Collections and Single Types)